# Fitting sklearn model inside pandas UDF is taking too long -PYSPARK-

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `spark.DataFrame`, with multiples time series. I want to apply a `sklearn` model for each time serie on a groupby apply. For each time series, the model takes app 0.05s, but when I try to solve this inside a `pandas_udf`, it takes much longer than applying it sequentially. Here is an example

```
def forecaster_spark(data_group: pd.DataFrame):
    # index for reports
    item_id = data_group["item_id"].iloc[0]
    # Indexing by time index
    data_group = data_group.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data_group['ds'])).sort_index()
    # Here we extract the time series
    y = data_group["y"].astype(float)
    # transform is a transformation to build regressor features (example extracting lags)
    X = transform(y)
    model = xg.XGBRegressor(max_depth = 50)
    # For each item, the model takes app 0.05s
    model.fit(X[:-1],y[-2])
    return pd.DataFrame({"item_id": item_id, "pred": model.predict(X.iloc[-1], y[-1])})
```

Here `transform` is a transformation applied on y to build a regressor matrix, for instance, could be thought of as a transformation that builds the lags.

Then I apply this on a `spark.DataFrame` containing all data

```
predictions = data.applyInPandas(forecaster_spark, schema="item_id string, y_pred double")
```

When I do an action on `predictions` (for example `toPandas` or `show(1000)`) it takes much time. When I comment `model.fit` on `forecaster_spark` (changing the `pred` return for any value) it finishes very fast, so the problem is on fitting the model inside the UDF. I thought that it could be a problem with the partition of the data frame when using groupby, but I tried with many simple UDF functions (for example taking mean) and the behavior was normal. Here is a function that works perfectly

```
def test_function_for_udf(data_group: pd.DataFrame):
    """Same function as above, but commenting fit method"""
    # index for reports
    item_id = data_group["item_id"].iloc[0]
    # Indexing by time index
    data_group = data_group.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data_group['ds'])).sort_index()
    # Here we extract the time series
    y = data_group["y"].astype(float)
    # transform is a transformation to build regressor features (example extracting lags)
    X = transform(y)
    model = xg.XGBRegressor(max_depth = 50)
    # Note that I commented the fit
    # model.fit(X[:-1],y[-2])
    return pd.DataFrame({"item_id": item_id, "mean": y.mean()})
```

Comment: when you run it 'sequentially' do you re-using the model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want it to run faster, try translate to [spark pandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/transform_apply.html) instead of pandas. (Admittedly it's not clear you could be using spark pandas.)
2. UDF's generally don't perform well. (They used to not get vectorized, but there has been recent work on this.)  If you want better performance, consider re-writing this as `.mapPartitions`  This will allow you to keep heavy objects in memory(`model = xg.XGBRegressor(max_depth = 50)`), instead of creating them to throw them away --> what happens in a UDF.
3. You will also likely get a better performance if you change the code to use a `yield` instead of `return`(within .mapParitions).  This is because spark uses lazy iterators and this can help with JVM memory pressure.  (This also allows data to be spilt from memory.) This isn't a magic bullet but a tool you might benefit from, that could be beneficial depending on the size of your group.

Comment: Thank you, worked well using pandas API. Do you have an idea about this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72997320/understanding-pyspark-apply-on-groupby/73019121#comment128972032_73019121

Answer (score 0):

You can perform distributed *training* of XGBoost models using either:

- [`xgboost.spark`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/spark_estimator.html) - probably the easiest option, but still experimental and needs version>=1.7.0
- `sparkdl.xgboost`

Databricks has some helpful tutorials on this:

> - [Distributed training of XGBoost models using xgboost.spark (Databricks Runtime 12.0 ML and above)](https://docs.databricks.com/machine-learning/train-model/xgboost-spark.html)
> - [Distributed training of XGBoost models using sparkdl.xgboost (deprecated starting with Databricks Runtime 12.0 ML)](https://docs.databricks.com/machine-learning/train-model/sparkdl-xgboost.html)

If you need other algorithms [`MLlib`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.ml.html) provides distributed versions of many of the most common ones