# Understanding pyspark apply on groupby

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm using the [pandas API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html) on Spark on Azure Databricks, and I have a very big `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame`, call `data`, containing sales information (as time series) for different products that can be identified by the `sku_id` column and the sales information can be identified with `target` column. I have a function `forecast` that implements a forecast for each `sku_id`. I thought it would be as easy as `data.groupby("sku_id").target.apply(forecast)`, but the time series that enter the `forecast` function are partitioned, i.e `forecast` is not seeing the complete time series for each sku. I understand that some functions like `len` can operate on batches and then merge the results in a easy way (
adding the results of each partition), `forecast` is not the case, It needs the whole time series for each sku. I checked that the time series are being partitioned raising an error if `forecast` is being evaluated with a short series, like this

```py
def forecast(y):
    if len(y) <= 100:
        raise NotImplementedError("Serie too short")
    # Do the forecast...
```

I'm sure that for each `sku_id` the observations are larger than 100 (much more), but the `apply` fails with the `NotImplementedError`, so the time series are being partitioned

So I want to understand how to apply a method like `forecast` on a groupby operation without partitioning the time series. I have not found documentation about it, and I want to know if this could be done or if it's a good practice.

Or maybe the approach is other: how to partition my data frame so that each series of `sku_id` is in the same partition?

**EDIT**

It works for

- `applyInPandas` for spark Data Frame
- Spark Pandas API and specifying the return type in the forecast function, it runs without problems and does not enter the raise

```
def forecast(y) -> float:
    if len(y) <= 100:
        raise NotImplementedError("Serie too short")
    # Do the forecast...
```

Why does the latter happen? The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python//reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) says

> this API executes the function once to infer the type which is potentially expensive, for instance, when the dataset is created after aggregations or sorting. To avoid this, specify return type in func, for instance, as below

Probably it tries to infer the return types to define the schema with a subsample at first instance?

Comment: Do you convert your DF from spark DF to pandas? What forecast model is this function applying?

Comment: No I don't. I worked with pandas API on spark only (never transformed to `pandas.DataFrame`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [code itself](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/group_ops.py) it provides some hints. That code eventually leads you down the path to [where it infers schema.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e1020a241a0a01e7430484878198281e0d8c8cf0/python/pyspark/sql/session.py).  To me this shows where your code could fail.  This is because it would at that time raise your error.

```
 first = rdd.first()
```

Diving a little further, it also shows how you could turn off this behaviour and instead use a sampled approach: `spark.sql.pyspark.legacy.inferArrayTypeFromFirstElement.enabled`

Disabling this setting would give you proof if that was in fact the issue.  If you selected a sample size that was at least bigger than your required `len(100)`

You could also likely fix the issue by removing the `raise`.  Which causes the issue.  You could still track any sets under 100 by using an [accumulator](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-accumulator-with-example/). These are made to track this type of data oddity and might be a better call if you don't want to blow up things but still track counts of odd situations like less than 100 time series events.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you repartition and cache your Spark DF?:

```
data = data\
            .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, ['sku_id'])\
            .cache()
```

And don't use `.toPandas()` but work with a `pandas_udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf( result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP )
def forecast(y):
    if len(y) <= 100:
        raise NotImplementedError("Serie too short")
    # Do the forecast...

#Then call the UDF to build the forecasts:

results = (
  data
    .groupBy('sku_id')
    .apply(forecast_store_item)
    )
```

This was extracted from [here](https://databricks.com/notebooks/fine-grained-demand-forecasting.html). Maybe gives you some good insight

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try the repartition method (I have to read about it first). What do you mean for "don't use `toPandas()`? I have never called that method. I worked using pandas on spark [oficial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html)  API.  If you work with Spark Data Frame you could use `pandas_udf`, but spark recommend to use `applyInPandas` method (which is a pandas udf at the end)